# Horizontal count in SQL

Tags: mysql

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVIRc.png)

This is a table which store the attendance of students which have 15 sessions. ATD means attended and ABS means Absent and MED means Medical. I need to count how many days attended and how many days absent as well as average. if any session a medical it is not taken as absent.

Comment: Repeating groups are almost always a sign of poor database design. They make doing easy things hard. You should consider normalizing this table to first normal form. Then easy things will be easy.

Comment: `SELECT (s1='ATD')+(s2='ATD')+...+(s15='ATD') AS ATD_amount, ...`. But the normalization is the best option.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you kindly help me to normalize this?

Answer (score 0):

Considering only the first 4 columns, a normalised design might look like this (although I suspect it would be more usual to store a 1 or a 0 in place of ATD/ABS :

```
student_id* s* value
377         1  ATD
377         2  ATD
377         3  ATD
378         1  ATD
378         2  ATD
378         3  ABS
381         1  ATD
381         2  ATD
381         3  ATD
382         1  ATD
382         2  ATD
382         3  ATD
```

`*` = (component of) PRIMARY KEY